# DigitalOcean Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Tags: ssh, digital-ocean

I am trying to access my droplet though ssh, however i keep getting the same message Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey). I searched for online solutions - changing the mod of the .ssh folder and authorization_keys, changing sshd_config file but nothing has worked. 
Initially, i used the public key in the digitalcloud interface and after that manually added a new ssh key though console panel.
Could you help me with solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing happen to me but my situation was I had a ppk file loaded in pageant, plus referenced in putty. But what bit me was I also had an id_rsa file under the $USER_HOME/.ssh folder. Most everything will defer to id_rsa as your default private key. I renamed id_rsa to id_rsa-backup and retried. Problem went away.

Comment: I'm using a fresh debian instance and my key is in authorized_keys. I don't have an id_rsa file, but still same issue.

Answer (score -2):

Check your public key, might have a copy/past error

You need to download the puttyGEN and generate a public and a private key save the private and public keys to a file. Then run pageant.exe and right-click on the pageant icon in the notification area and add the private key you just saved. Now add the public key to the server in your account.